# Проверка на наличие поля Sqlite по уникальному столбцу

Tags: java, android, sqlite

В моём приложении у пользователя будет возможность отметить понравившееся ему изображение и это изображение перейдёт из table "category_name" в table"favourite", при этом мне нужно избежать чтобы данная запись не могла добавляться несколько раз, для этого мне нужно реализовать функцию, которая определяет по уникальному полю title, есть ли запись с таким именем в table"favourite", я нашёл что-то типа этого:

```
public boolean isFavourite(int position) {
        String selection = myTemplates.get(position).getTitle();

        Cursor c = mDb.query("favourites", null, selection, null, null, null,
                null);

        boolean result = c.getCount() > 0;
        c.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Но это вызывает исключение, потому что я не знаю, есть ли тут возможность указать колонну, по которой идёт поиск

Comment: Если вы будете использовать библиотеку Room то сможете писать SQL запросы и не мучиться с курсорами)

Comment: У меня достаточно большая БД, ещё и загруженная готовая. Я бы изучил Room, но времени нет, 21 защита проекта((

Comment: Судя по Гуглу есть метод rawQuery, в который можно любой sql запрос передать. Используйте его, если не можете разобраться как сделать иначе

Comment: таблица favourite выглядит лишней, достаточно поля в основной таблице. переносить из одной таблицы в другую - это не true.